# What's c++11 standard's equivalent for the deprecated std::auto_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some code that uses `std::auto_ptr` and gives ugly warnings about deprecated `std::auto_ptr` (GCC 4.7.1 on Suse Linux 12.2) when compiling.

So I have tried the following (since I found some source that states `std::unique_ptr` should be the appropriate equivalent)

```
template<typename T>
struct AutoPtr
{
#ifdef COMPILE_FOR_CX11
    typedef std::unique_ptr<T> Type;
#else
    typedef std::auto_ptr<T> Type;
#endif
};
```

and replaced any references to `std::auto_ptr<T>` with `AutoPtr<T>::Type`, but got compile errors when using this option.

I'm pretty sure I want to use something like `std::auto_ptr` at these pieces of code and I'm aware about the culprits and deficiencies of it. The errors I get seem to correlate about construction issues when `std::unique_ptr` is used.

As a side note: The final class used for construction is an inheriting type of `T`, the code looks like:

```
class MockClass;

class Client
{
public:
    Client();
    Client(const Client& rhs);

private:
    mutable AutoPtr<MockClass>::Type embeddedMock;
};
```

---

```
Client::Client()
: embeddedMock(new ::testing::NiceMock<MockClass>())
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Getting errors here!
{
}


Client::Client(const Client& rhs)
: embeddedMock(rhs.embeddedMock)
{
}
```

So what's a full compliant smart pointer from the c++11 set, I can use here?

Comment: The wrapper class is a bit pointless. You can just say `#define AutoPtr std::auto_ptr` etc. and then say `AutoPtr<T>`.

Comment: What's the compile error?

Comment: It should be `mutable AutoPtr<MockClass>::Type embeddedMock;`

Comment: @AndyProwl Yes, was a 'typo'! Edited that ...

Comment: @g-makulik: It seems to work [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=dea794f30cda8cfa4c504829545cf5d3-9a9914b3e2b7ed07c206d6accecccdb6)

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm just cautious about needing more adaptions besides the type ...

Comment: @DavidBrown Not sure! I've replicated the code to reduce to the pattern. But I thought it was at the line with the `new` ...

Comment: @AndyProwl Sorry for all the hype! Yes, when I remove 'typos' in my real code it compiles well, as you expected. What should we do with this question? Is there already a canonical question about `std::auto_ptr` porting to `std::unique_ptr` around?

Comment: @AndyProwl: Ouch! `mutable`? ouch! That is abusing the intent of `mutable` to work around a different limitation of the design. Two wrongs don't make one right, even if it compiles.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I just meant to fix the error with the template instantiation, not to provide an answer :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Finally I have removed those copy constructors now, since they're not needed at all. No need for mutable then (there's no assignment operator defined either) ... (And yes: Ouch! Didn't feel good with this, was an XYZ problem)

Comment: The fully compliant smart pointer for `std::auto_ptr` is `std::auto_ptr`. It's deprecated, which means that it **might** go away in some future version of the standard. Until that happens, it's part of the standard. That said, if you use it you have to live with it's somewhat quirky behavior. But that's nothing new.

Comment: @PeteBecker Could you clarify about the differences now, and how a surrogate should be used/implemented?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`unique_ptr` is the C++11 replacement facility for `auto_ptr`.  However, it's not a drop-in replacement, since `auto_ptr` had transfer-of-ownership-on-copy semantics and `unique_ptr` forces you to transfer ownership explicitly.  When you have something like this:

```
auto_ptr<Foo> x(new Foo());
// ...
auto_ptr<Foo> y = x;
// ...
bar( y ); // copies y into bar(), transferring ownership
```

. . . to use `unique_ptr`, you would need to add `move()` to the ownership-transfer sites:

```
unique_ptr<Foo> x(new Foo());
// ...
unique_ptr<Foo> y = move(x);
// ...
bar( move(y) );
```

**EDIT:**

Without knowing what specific error you're getting, it's hard to tell why your default constructor is failing to compile.  However, your copy constructor should fail to compile with `unique_ptr` unless `move` is added.

Comment: But that what's the purpose of the `mutable` statement was for. I've shortly seen an answer from a reputable SO member that showed how to use transferring ownership of `std::unique_ptr` explicitly, which would be compliant with `std::auto_ptr`. Introducing move semantics (for code that should compile well for c++ old and cx11 standards) isn't much of a help here :(

Comment: @g-makulik, right, missed the `mutable` part.  Sorry.  (Answer edited to correct the copy constructor reference.)  If you want to make code that works under C++11 and C++98, you can always introduce a dummy `move`-type operation that compiles out under C++98.  I.e. something like: `#ifdef CPP11`|`#define MOVE(X) ::std::move(X)`|`#else`|`#define MOVE(X) X`|`#endif`